# Android - Include GitHub Library ActionBar PullToRefresh

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

i have a problem with including a library from GitHub.

This is the library:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

I've downloaded this and then went in eclipse to "Import"->"Existing projects into workspace" and then selected the downloaded directory.

But i get the error: "no projects are found to import".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you click on import you should then click on the "Android" folder, then "Existing Android Projects into Workspace." It seems you are using "Existing Project into Workspace" under the "General" folder.

Comment: THANK YOU! That was the solution. ;) The "Android" folder ... many thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding. Please mark this question as answered

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it is working perfectly fine make sure you check the checkbox copy project into workspace.[image]

Comment: That's great i just wanted you to get out of the problem. :)