# Actionbar Gradle GROUP for class: org.gradle.api. Error

Tags: gradle

Well i am implementing actionbar pull refresh library into my demotool project
i follow this link and at last i am already at finish line 
my code error is

`Gradle 'demotool' project refresh failed: No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer`

[Implementing ActionBar-PulltoRefresh by Chris Banes, libary errors etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20527332/3032499)

but i am getting this error which i cant find on google because no one have this error
i will first give you my project structure

[demotool]

|-> **settings.gradle**
    include ':app',':actionbarsherlock',':pulltorefresh'
|

|-> **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
```

|
|-> **pulltorefresh**
   |-> **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.2.0'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 14
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            // This should be 14, but is 7 because extra-abc/extra-abs depend on this library
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
            }
        }
    }

    apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

|
|-> **actionbarsherlock**
    |-> **build.gradle**
apply plugin: 'android-library'

```
    dependencies {
        compile files('actionbarsherlock/android-support-v4.jar')
        compile ("com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:[4.4,)@aar") {
            // Need to specifically exclude this as it is specified in ActionBarSherlock pom
            exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 14
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
            }
        }
    }

    apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

|-> **demotool(app)**
    |-> **build.gradle**
    apply plugin: 'android'

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile project(":actionbarsherlock")
            compile project(":pulltorefresh")
    }
```

what is this error and why i am getting this.
and tell me if this structure is OK?
and yes sometimes **i get default configuration error too**
thanks in advance

Answer (score 23):

`PullToRefresh/build.gradle` applies the `gradle-mvn-push.gradle` plugin, but in your project you don't need/want that. If you comment out the line:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

your project should build successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your `gradle.properties` seems to be missing a `GROUP` property, which is required by `gradle-mvn-push.gradle` (see its GitHub page).

Comment: OK search on stackoverflow with github actiobar i got this which is easy process then going through all these steps..

Answer (score 1):

The original source code has gradle.properties file which contains values for all the properties you need to copy that too...